"Could not find a package configuration file provided" CMAKE error while trying to configurate custom ros package called "robotx_msgs"
I successfully cloned the repository from: https://github.com/OUXT-Polaris/robotx_packages.git
When I try to configurate the cloned package via using catkin_make command I get this Cmake error:
-- Could not find the required component 'robotx_msgs'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "robotx_msgs" with
  any of the following names:

    robotx_msgsConfig.cmake
    robotx_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "robotx_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "robotx_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "robotx_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  robotx_packages/robotx_tools/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I get this cmake error from another files but they are not a custom ros package, so I was  able to sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-(packagename) to solve them. However, as I mentioned robotx_msgs package is custom and I couldn't find a solution for thıs problem.
